# How to add click listener to custom relativeLayout

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-custom-view

I need a custom relativeLayout because I will use it many times in the different listview. And whichever listview it is, the click listener of the custom relativeLayout is same intent that is to start one activity. So I write click listener in this class, rather than getView() in adapter.
I want to add click listener to custom relativeLayout, and I add the custom relativeLayout as a item to a listview, but when I click the item, listener don't work.
What should I do? Please help.

Custom relativeLayout:

```
public class SearchCourseItem extends RelativeLayout {

    @Bind(R.id.iv_search_course)
    ImageView mIvSearchCourse;
    @Bind(R.id.tv_search_course_title)
    TextView mTvSearchCourseTitle;
    @Bind(R.id.tv_search_course_detail)
    TextView mTvSearchCourseDetail;

    private SearchCourseEntity.DataEntity datas;

    public SearchCourseItem(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public void init(Context context) {
        setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_search_course, this);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    public void setData(SearchCourseEntity.DataEntity datas) {
        this.datas = datas;
        mTvSearchCourseDetail.setText(datas.getDescription());
        mTvSearchCourseTitle.setText(datas.getName());
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(datas.getPicture(), mIvSearchCourse, UILHelper.getMediumPlaceHolderBaseBuilder().build());
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        if (datas.getType().equals("workout")) {
            intent.setClass(getContext(), DailyTrainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("workoutid", datas.getId());
        } else {
            intent.setClass(getContext(), PlanActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("planid", datas.getId());
        }
        getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        SearchCourseItem searchCourseItem;
        if (convertView != null && convertView instanceof SearchCourseItem) {
            searchCourseItem = (SearchCourseItem) convertView;
        } else {
            searchCourseItem = new SearchCourseItem(mContext);
        }
        searchCourseItem.setData(mDataEntities.get(position));
        return searchCourseItem;
    }
```

Comment: try by adding a listener to your convertView inside getView method

Comment: You are overriding `setOnClickListener` instead of calling it and passing an listener. I guess that is, why no click is triggered.

Comment: Can you please describe why you need a custom RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't override

```
public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l)
```

Move the code to an onClickListener and set it in your getView().

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SearchCourseItem searchCourseItem;
    if (convertView != null && convertView instanceof SearchCourseItem) {
        searchCourseItem = (SearchCourseItem) convertView;
    } else {
        searchCourseItem = new SearchCourseItem(mContext);
    }
    searchCourseItem.setData(mDataEntities.get(position));
searchCourseItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            if (searchCourseItem.getData().getType().equals("workout")) { //Don't know, if that is what you want!!!
                intent.setClass(getContext(), DailyTrainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("workoutid", datas.getId());
            } else {
                intent.setClass(getContext(), PlanActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("planid", datas.getId());
            }
            getContext().startActivity(intent);   
        }
    });

    return searchCourseItem;
}
```

EDIT: Alternative you could set an onClickListener in the constructor. Still no need to override setOnClickListener.

```
public SearchCourseItem(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
    super.setOnClickListener(...);
}
```

Comment: I will use the custom relativeLayout many times, and in the different listview and different adapter, so I want write the code in the custom relativeLayout.

Comment: You could also set a listener in the constructor of your layout. See my edits.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try onclick listener to your convertView

Code:

yourview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Do something
            }
        });

return yourview;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was doing something that looks like what you do but in a `RecyclerView.Adapter`, with my custom view's constructor inflating `list_item.xml` into each new instance. Then in my adapter I was attaching my listener in the `onBindViewHolder()` method. But even if in theory it seemed to be done the right way, **it wasn't working until I removed the `android:clickable="true"` attribute from my `list_item.xml`'s root layout**.